# Chrome console drawer not displaying console tab content

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome developer tools includes a "show console drawer" setting.  The console tab in the drawer does not show any content.  When I click on another tab like search, it expands to see the content.

Why is the console tab not showing content like the search tab (and others)?

Nothing shows when console is clicked:

[image: Console tab in drawer]

Content is displayed with search is clicked:
[image: Search tab in drawer]

Comment: Click `6 messages` in the left panel. You currently see only the output from console.info().

Comment: I would like to see the console in the drawer display the messages.  I have always used the top panel to toggle between console, sources, and network.  Shouldn't the drawer allow me to always see console, no matter what I was looking at in the top panel?

Comment: There's only one console internally so apparently the filter is applied to both views.

Answer (score 0):

Today when I opened my browser, I have the following behavior:

Clicking the console tab in the top section, the drawer console is collapsed.
[image: Console tab active, Drawer collapsed]

Clicking any other tab in the top section, the drawer console is expanded.
[image: Other tabs active, Drawer expanded]

It appears as if the console will only appear in one location.

Regardless, I can see both console and network simultaneously which is what I needed.  Thanks to all who responded.